# NextJS type error while passing props to children

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a type file with these types:

```
type IServiceItems = {
  fields: {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    logo: {
      fields: {
        file: {
          url: string;
        };
      };
    };
  };
};

type ITechItems = {
  fields: {
    name: string;
    logo: {
      fields: {
        file: {
          url: string;
        };
      };
    };
  };
};
```

I have a page where I am fetching data with SSR props. I am trying to pass these props to children. But I am getting type error.

The page tsx file:

```
interface Props {
  services: IServiceItems[];
  technologies: ITechItems[];
}

const Index = ({ services, technologies }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ServicesBlock services={...services} />
      <TechnologiesBlock technologies={...technologies} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The error on services and technologies properties:

```
(property) services: IServiceItems[]
Type '{ services: IServiceItems[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IServiceItems[]'.
  Property 'services' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IServiceItems[]'.
```

And finally the component:

```
const ServicesBlock = (services: IServiceItems[]) => {}
```

I tried to use `...` when passing the params but did not help.

The data fetch:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const services = await contentful.getEntries({ content_type: 'service' });
  const technologies = await contentful.getEntries({ content_type: 'technology' });

  return {
    props: {
      services: services.items,
      technologies: technologies.items,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Where is the `getStaticProps` call? Did you just omit it? That's the data fetching mechanism.

Comment: You need to isolate the error. Is your fetch successful? Try to log `services` in the the `page.tsx`. You might also have a TS problem. Why are your interfaces named arrays like that? Could be your type check is failing but the fetch works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't spread your `services` array when passing it as a prop if you are expecting an array (remove the `...`):

```
const Index = ({ services, technologies }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ServicesBlock services={services} />
      <TechnologiesBlock technologies={technologies} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Also, change your `ServicesBlock` declaration as:

```
interface Props {
    services: IServiceItems[];
}

const ServicesBlock = ({ services }: Props) => {}
```